# Creating an algebraic formula

Tags: geometry

I need to create a formula for a piece of software and can't quite work out how to form it as my Maths is a little rusty.  I would appreciate any help.

I have two values X & Y where each can be between 0 and 1.0

Their relationship is shown below in the picture but has the equation

$y=√(1−x^2)$

I have added an image showing their relationship.
[image]

I need a formula that returns ~1 as X & Y comes equal to each other and tends to 0 when they aren't (i.e X=1,Y=0).  Basically to know (in terms of $[0,1]$) when the point on the line is in the most upper right of the line.

Apologies if I haven't explained well enough.

Thanks

Comment: Indeed, the explanation is not very clear. But still, I have a guess. Is the graph part of a **circle**? In that case, you can try
$$
x^2 + y^2 = 1
$$
or
$$
y= \sqrt{1-x^2}
$$
Would these satisfy you?

Comment: Yes it is a circle (or part of), I am effectivly looking for an equation that that returns 1 when a point is in the upper right most position, and tends to 0 when either X or Y goes to 1.

Comment: What about $1-|x-y|$? Would that work?

Comment: @Kyky Although that gives a value of 0 when X or Y is 1, it doesn't give an answer of 1 when X & Y are 0.71 (which is roughly the point where they are equal

Comment: Hm, yes it does? When $x=y=\frac{\sqrt2}2$ then $1-|x-y|=0$, no?

Comment: @Kyky Sorry I don't follow

Comment: Ah, sorry, made a typo, should be $1-|x-y|=1-\left|\frac{\sqrt2}2-\frac{\sqrt2}2\right|=1-|0|=1$. Point is when $x=y$ then my function gives out $1$, as you requested.

Comment: And if you want a function purely in terms of $x$, then you can write $1-\left|x-\sqrt{1-x^2}\right|$

Comment: @Kyky Ah thanks yeah that makes sense - If you want to add your comment as answer I will mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $f=1-|x-y|=1-\left|x-\sqrt{1-x^2}\right|$

When $x=0$ and $y=1$ then $f=1-|0-1|=1-|-1|=1-1=0$

When $x=1$ and $y=0$ then $f=1-|1-0|=1-|1|=1-1=0$

When $x=y=\frac{\sqrt2}2$ then $f=1-\left|\frac{\sqrt2}2-\frac{\sqrt2}2\right|=1-|0|=1-0=1$